# How do I navigate to a samba location I've mounted in Nautilus on the command line?

Tags: command-line, samba

Please note: I am two weeks old in Linux. I have found a lot of answers to this question on the internet, tried many, but all failed one way or another. Therefore I dare to ask once again in the hope that someone here could explain it simply :)

Pre-conditions:

In my institute, we have a Samba server. In Windows, it is accessed by going to `\\xyz.220.131.233\` and entering the login `abc` and the password `def`.

In Ubuntu, I was able to do exactly the same using Nautilus, pressing Ctrl+L and entering `smb://xyz.220.131.233/`. It then asks for the login and the password and connects. I can even drag a folder from here to the 'Places' and have a shortcut to the remote location.

So far so good. I've just installed Matlab and want to open this remote location. Trying to `cd` to `smb://xyz.220.131.233/` returns

> Cannot CD to smb://xyz.220.131.233 (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).

A Mac user in my group told me I first mount the location, but he didn't know how to do it.

Is it true and how do I do it?

Comment: Similar [Q/A for Debian](http://superuser.com/q/717893/79304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, not sure if this is the real answer (please comment if in doubt or checked it yourself), but after some struggling together with another Linux colleague I've realised that I actually was not in the users group in my system (`nano /etc/group`). Upon adding myself to this group (`sudo nano /etc/group`, adding my name to the `users` line), I am now able to access the remote directories. My /etc/fstab file has these lines:

```
//xxx.220.131.233/user  /mnt/rua_user  cifs  username=abc,password=def 0 1
//xxx.220.131.233/all   /mnt/rua_all   cifs  username=abc,password=def 0 1
```

The rights on the folders look like this (`ls -lh /mnt`):

```
drwxrwx---  8 1016 users 0 2011-03-08 11:14 rua_all
drwxrwx--- 25 1016 users 0 2011-05-25 18:21 rua_user
```

Answer (score 89):

#### In most cases:

```
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs
```

#### 14.04:

```
/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs
```

#### 12.10:

```
/run/user/<username>/gvfs
```

#### 12.04:

Since 12.04 the folder of mounted samba share is:

```
~/.cache/gvfs
```

#### 11.10 and older

You can learn how to mount - it will sure works.  But I think this is an easier solution for you: Nautilus mount smb partitions at `~/.gvfs` (where ~/ means /home/user_name/ - example: `/home/desgua/.gvfs`).
You just have to navigate to there:

```
cd ~/.gvfs
```

Comment: Beautiful! Linux has an incredible amount of features! I wonder what is the way to learn such details though... Thanks!

Comment: it seems that the newest Ubuntu puts the mounts in ~/.cache/gvfs/ instead.

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu Quantal), it's mounted in `/run/user/<username>/gvfs`.

Comment: why do they change it every version?

Comment: I'm on 12.04, and it's mounted to `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: I think the location has moved after an update.

Comment: 14.04 same as 12.10.  User as number not name on my system like  /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=NAS,share=MyShareFolder

Comment: $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR  == /run/user/$(id -u) : on (14.04)

Comment: What's funny is none of those locations contain the shared files.  Do they exist in neverland then?  Is there a way to determine the actual share path and not just seeing a list of default paths as mentioned here?

Answer (score 7):

Another option here, while not directly related to having mounted the directory in nautilus is to mount the location from the command line.

However, to mount samba volumes, you have to have CIFS support.

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

From here, you have the option of where you want to mount the location. There are TWO "standards" of sorts for this. If you want the location to show up in the Places menu, you would mount it in `/media`. If not, you would mount it in `/mnt` (only to follow the common namespace for mounted volumes. There’s nothing wrong with mounting the directory in `/home/$user/mount/someshare`)

[image]

<sup>Illustration of the mounted location in the Places menu</sup>

assuming that `/media/myshare` exist, you would achieve this by issuing the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=abc,password=def //xyz.220.131.233 /media/myshare
```

#### Side note

You can accomplish this automagically by appending the following string to your `/etc/fstab` configuration:

```
//xyz.220.131.233 /media/SambaMount cifs username=abc,password=def,rw,user,noauto 0 0
```

Notice the `noauto` flag, this will keep the volume from being mounted at boot, so when you're no longer at your workplace, it won't hang during boot trying to poll and mount that share.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, I was distracted by some urgent work and had to switch back to Windows for a while. This suggestion somehow doesn't work: I am getting a 'Retrying with upper case share name. mount error(6): No such device or address' error. Something similar is described at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=195264

Comment: I've realised that was probably my mistake. I should have mounted //xyz.220.131.233/foldername rather than the whole server. After correcting for this, I don't get an error any more and can see the /myshare folder appeared in Places in Nautilus. However, when trying to browse it, I get 'The folder contents could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "myshare"'. What's wrong?

Comment: Check that you have permissions to access the resource by both the user on the remote system that your using to mount it (in the mount string) as well as the user account used to create the mount on your local machine.

Comment: Aha, slowly progressing :) If I launch Nautilus with sudo, I can browse the /myshare location. Now how do I mount it in such a way that I can access it as a normal user (texnic)? I can access the remote location as a normal user, as far as I understand, since I can browse to smb://xyz.220.131.233/foldername in Nautilus launched without sudo. And, on the other hand, why do I get 'Permission denied' if I try to execute 'cd /media/myshare' and at the same time I get 'command not found' for 'sudo cd /media/myshare'?

Comment: You'd have to add the user flag in your mount options, either via fstab or during the issued mount command. eg: -o user

Comment: After reading http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html, I also thought so but it seems not to be necessary. See my answer below.

Comment: ERROR: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on smb://computer/dev,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

Answer (score 4):

in **ubuntu 16.04** and vlc 2.2.2 ;

Select `media > Open Directory` and navigate to `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`  << ID number (1000) can be vary on your system.

Here you can see the shared folder name and select the folder whichever you want to add in playlist (see picture below)

[image: vlc add dierctory]

Answer (score 2):

On **12.10** you can find the location at

```
/run/user/USERNAME/gvfs/
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04 I'm running:

```
~/.gvfs/[SHARENAME]
```

`~/.cache/` only contains a folder `gvfs-burn`

Answer (score 1):

Follow this page. I followed it to get the same result as what you are looking for.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 1):

in some of latest (e.g., 13.XX, 14.XX) ubuntu , you need to go to

```
/run/user/(USERID)/gvfs/
```

to find the mounted location. here (UID) is the UID of the account, which can be found by the command

```
id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s "/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=Name_server/Path_Directory_source_in/Path_file.pdf" /Path_directory_source_out/Path_file.pdf
```

This is my example of how to make a file link from terminal in Ubuntu.

Use double quotes "" to escape special characters such as spaces