# Mercurial central repository at a Samba location

Tags: samba, mercurial

I have a remote Samba location mounted as /mnt/rua as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/33480/12938). I have created a folder HgRepository there, which is my central Mercurial repo. I am working with a local clone and push the setting to this folder. My team-mates do the same on their machines.

Now, the problem is that Mercurial returns

> abort: could not lock repository /mnt/rua/HgRepository/spectrometry: Permission denied

if I am trying to do `hg push`. With `hg pull` as well as with `sudo hg push` everything works fine. This would be ok, but the problem is that the Nautilus Mercurial extension (TortoiseHg) works in the non-sudo mode, so the context menu command for pushing doesn't work.

How should I properly change the settings to make it work?

In case it helps, here is what I get for `ls -l /mnt`

> drwxrwx---  8 1016 users 0 2011-06-10 12:47 rua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is a single-user machine and that your user ID is 1000 (you can check if it is by running `id` in a terminal).

As far as I understand, your /etc/fstab has something like/etc/fstab as follows:

```
//x.x.x.x/sharename  /mnt/rua  cifs  username=abc,password=def 0 1
```

Add `forceuid,uid=1000` flags to it:

```
//x.x.x.x/sharename  /mnt/rua  cifs  username=abc,password=def,forceuid,uid=1000 0 1
```

then re-mount the share with

```
sudo umount /mnt/rua
sudo mount /mnt/rua
```

and check with ls -l that you see

```
drwxrwx--- 8 <yourusernamehere> users 0 2011-06-10 12:47 rua
```

Now you should be able to fully access the share's contents without becoming root.

Comment: Works like a charm. This forcing (forceuid in fstab) — is it very unsafe?

Comment: Well, if you have multiple users on this machine, forceuid will make them all able to access all the files.  If you want more fine-grained protection, don't use forceuid, but then you'll have to synchronize the username -> uid mappings on the server and all the clients.

If this is a single-user machine, there's no downside to using forceuid.