# Nautilus' remote folder default mount point

Tags: nautilus, mount, ssh, sftp

I connect a remote folder in Nautilus (file info says that it is done via sftp), and within it the folder becomes fully browseable.
But I can't access it from the other applications: I couldn't find the mount point.
I wonder what is the default mount point?

UPD: I use Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remote folder *mounts* are only available to other applications which are using the `gvfs` APIs for file operations, and which claim to support remote file operations when creating the file chooser dialog, to open files.

These folders aren't *mounted* in the typical sense of the word, as they are virtual file systems managed by gvfs. However, they can be accessed in applications which only support classic POSIX file operation calls, by looking under the `~/.gvfs/` or `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` directory (where `$UID` is your user ID), to browse the *mounts* and files within, if you have the `gvfs-fuse` package installed. You may need to unmount and re-mount the remote directory after installing, or possibly even log out and back in.

Comment: I don't have ~/.gvfs folder. What's the way of telling Nautilus to use it?

Comment: Updated answer, the location was moved in some recent version of gvfs. And the gvfs-fuse package is required.

Comment: This can be accessed easily with `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/33513/1022993)