# Nautilus: Remotely accessed files are wrongly mounted in a temp dir

Tags: upgrade, mount, ssh, nautilus, gvfs

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to a new device running 18.04.

On the old device, when using nautilus to connect to servers via SFTP/SSH the file paths were mounted as `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=$SERVER$ABSOLUTE_PATH$FILE` when editing them.

With the new device the files are instead mounted as `/run/user/1001/doc/$TEMP_ID/$FILE`.

The old system was more resilient to interruptions. If the connection was cut and then later established again files that are still open in the editor could be saved like nothing happened. With the temporary paths every file has to be re-opened each time.

How do I go about bringing back the more predictable behavior? Happy to provide more info, just not sure what the possible root causes are right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an old related [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281740/nautilus-remote-folder-default-mount-point)

Try to install `gvfs-fuse`:

```sh
apt install gvfs-fuse
```

And unmount and remount your sftp in your nautilus.

If that still doesn't work, try to manually start virtual mount with specific directory:

```sh
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs
```

Comment: Your answer did not solve the problem, but it helped me realize that I was looking in the wrong place, which ultimately lead to the solution. I awarded the bounty for that. I followed your answer, and learned that this is all set up already. After poking around some more it turns out that the problem was the flatpak version of Sublime. I reinstalled it straight from the website, and it works. No config required. I have had weird problems with other flatpak software in the past, so I'm going to leave it at that. Thank you for your time and for setting me on the right track!

Comment: I glad this could help you, although it is not the right solution.