# Mount point of network shared folder

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04

Where can I find the mount point of some network shared folder. For example, I shared folder `pac` from `MachineB`. That folder can already be seen/browsed from `MachineA` via `nautilus`.

But I need is a way to browse that `pac` folder from command line from `MachineA`. How can that be done?

Comment: Whats the output of `mount | grep pac`?

Comment: that command gives empty output from `MachineA`. From `MachineA` `nautilus` the folder was called `pac on 192.168.0.123` (which is the address of `MachineB`)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/33513/372607

Answer (score 2):

Mount:

`Nautilus > Go > Enter location > smb://192.168.0.123`

Then can find the shared folder in **`/$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`** (ref: EvanChen link  askubuntu.com/a/33513/372607)

Specifically on my 16.04

```
~$ cd /$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs
//run/user/1000/gvfs$ ls
smb-share:server=192.168.0.123,share=pac

//run/user/1000/gvfs$ cd smb-share:server=192.168.0.123,share=pac
//run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.123,share=pac$ pwd
//run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.123,share=pac
```

Then make a softlink from home folder:
    $ cd ~
    $ ln -s //run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.123,share=pac pac

Now `cd pac` and done, can browse the network shared folder from command line.