# Mount point of Samba via Xfce

Tags: samba, xfce, mountpoint

What directory does Xfce use when it mount Samba connection via own GUI File Manager (NetWork)?

I try to look /mnt, /media. They are empty.

I just want to use this mount point in a script and don't mount a new point.

Comment: The `findmnt`-command should show something useful.

Comment: @mook765 There is nothing like Samba. It seems that Xfce mount Samba inside itself. :(

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/33480/590937

Comment: @mook765 Thanks a lot. I just now read this post. I would want to point other posts: https://askubuntu.com/a/1159685/902490, https://askubuntu.com/q/33480/902490, https://askubuntu.com/q/343205/902490. If you formalize the answer I mark it as the solution.